# Oracle 11g - Temp Tablespace Segments don't get released (Oracle Bug?)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using *Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production* and i have a problem with the following query which i am executing in *TOAD 12.6.0.53* (not a typical query, but it is only for demonstration):

```
with rownums 
as (select distinct 
    rownum rn 
      from dual 
   connect by level <=1000000 
) 
select rn from rownums 
 union all
select rn from rownums;

--Edit: this Statement ist NOT showing the behaviour:
begin
    for cRow in (with rownums 
                as (select distinct 
                    rownum rn 
                      from dual 
                   connect by level <=1000000 
                ) 
                select rn from rownums 
                 union all
                select rn from rownums) 
    loop
        return;
    end loop;
end;
```

After executing this query, i can check the usage of the temp tablespace with this query:

```
SELECT S.sid, S.serial#, SUM (T.blocks) * TBS.block_size / 1024 / 1024 used_mb, T.tablespace
  FROM v$sort_usage T, v$session S, dba_tablespaces TBS
 WHERE T.session_addr = S.saddr
   AND T.tablespace = TBS.tablespace_name
   and s.sid = sys_context('userenv','sid')
 GROUP BY S.sid, S.serial#, TBS.block_size, T.tablespace;
```

The result is, that every execution of the testquery from above needs about 12MB of *Temp Tablespace* which is not getting released until i disconnect the session.
If i do this to often, it leads too an *ORA-1652: unable to extend temp segment*.

What am i doing wrong? Or could this be an oracle bug?

Comment: I'm not seeing that in 11.2.0.3 with the PL/SQL block, and a smaller effect with plain SQL. Is your temporary tablespace really temporary, or is it using permanent segments - what is dba_tablespaces.contents showing? (MOS note 1039341.6 might be relevant if you have access, since I can see v$sortsegments.user_blocks growing, again with plain SQL only).

Comment: Actually I'm not seeing it with the plain SQL version either, in SQL\*Plus; but I am seeing it in SQL Developer - only if there are rows from the result set that haven't been fetched and displayed - so the query is still active. I guess Toad is doing something similar?

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback, it was my Mistake regarding the PL/SQL Block, it is NOT showing the behaviour. I have checked the dba_tablespaces.contents - and it is "TEMPORARY" and not "PERMANENT"

Comment: I can reproduce from a simple Java program too (SQL Developer and Toad both run over JDBC); executing your query into a result set grabs the temporary space, and it isn't freed unless I loop over the entire result set. Closing the result set or prepared statement doesn't free the temporary segments, they are only freed after a `while (rSet.next()) {...}` loop completes. Which looks like a bug I think, but I can't see any obvious match in MOS - 18098207 *might* be related but hard to tell. Would be interesting to see if this is reproducible in other versions.

Comment: Doesn't quite reproduce in 10.2.0.5. Segments are not freed by rSet.close(), but a second execution seems to reuse the same ones, and they *are* freed by pStmt.close(). And are still freed by completely looping over the result set. I don't have any other versions handy to test on. Might be worth raising a service request about this behaviour.

Comment: If you have MOS access, this looks like 20401612, which is linked to 20477541 (which isn't visible), and possibly then 18004006. I think you need to raise a service request to get any more information though.

Comment: I recently run in the same issue. I used your sample query to open a service request. applying the patch for BUG-20133369 seems to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

TEMP Tablespace has some limited Disk space. When you run query it began to use TEMP space more and more and untill it reaches its limit and gives an error can't extend TEMP , So possible are two solutions

- Increase TEMP space better Using EM
- Optimize Query that uses less    TEMP